# Match string in a list python

Tags: python, string

i have a python list as follows

```
 List=['\Opt\mydata.cab','\my\ginger','\my\garbage','\my\hfs']
```

i have a string as given below

```
strin1="mydata\opt\mydata.cab"
```

is there any easy way to match the string in list '\Opt\mydata.cab' one line without a for loop like given below

```
if strin1 in List:
                print(strin1)
```

Comment: There is no `for` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Python doesn't have anything like that. But you can always use `any` function like this

```
if any(item in strin1 for item in List):
```

Still, this will look for exact match. If you want case-insensitive match you can convert both sides to lowercase.

The advantages of using `any` are

1. You don't have to roll your own function
2. It short-circuits immediately when the condition is satisfied for the first time
3. It works with any iterable

If you want to get the item which matches, you can use the `next` function like this

```
next(item for item in List if item in strin1)
```

You can also pass the default value to be returned if there is no match, like this

```
next(item for item in List if item in strin1, None)
```

Comment: how can i print this 'item'

Comment: @user1654136 Sure, I included a way to do that in the answer. Please check.

Comment: Not sure what changed since 2014, but I'd write it like: `next(item for item in list_of_items if string in item)`.